# Conditionally change envivornment variable after app is build in react native

Tags: android, react-native, environment-variables, devenv, react-native-config

I have configured react-native-config in my app, made two envs file i.e env.dev & env.prod. Now everything is working as per configuration.
But now I want to change env to dev or prod depending on the file downloaded from AWS S3 service( some third party service ). Is is possible to select env.dev or env.prod depending upon the file downloaded which will decide to select on of the env file?

I'm still trying to figure it out if it is possible to select env file upon app launch.